# How to count number of "I", "You", "We" in a Google Doc?

Tags: for-loop, google-docs, word-count

That is a simple way. If you have any more stunning solutions. You are welcome.
Feel free to use it. It works on my document.

The story started from a battle with my girlfriend, in the narrative style of a letter I have addressed her. I was quite impressed by the improvise good balance, the proportion of "I", "You", and to close the letter on "We", that I cannot accept her critics.

```
function myFunction_Count_YnInW() {
 
  var space = " ";
  var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();
  var words = text.replace(/\s+/g, space).split(space);
  var theCount_I = 0;
  var theCount_Y = 0;
  var theCount_W = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    var theWord = words.slice(i,i+1).toString().toLowerCase();
    if(theWord=="i"){
        theCount_I++;
//    }else if(theWord=="me"){
//        theCount_I++;
    }else if(theWord=="you"){
        theCount_Y++;
    }else if(theWord=="we"){
        theCount_W++;
    }else if(theWord=="us"){
        theCount_W++;
    }
  } 
  var message = "Here are the results : \n" 
  + "Number of words = "+ words.length + " \n"
  + "Number of 'I'= "+ theCount_I + " \n"
  + "Number of 'You'= "+ theCount_Y + " \n"
  + "Number of 'Us'= "+ theCount_W; 
  Logger.log(message);
  //DocumentApp.getUi().alert(message);
  return message;
  
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this because there is no question asked. OP is just trying to show their code off.

Answer (score -1):

So what i propose to optimise the script would be to add percentage in the results.

```
function myFunction_Count_YnInW() {
 
  var space = " ";
  var text = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getText();
  var words = text.replace(/\s+/g, space).split(space);
  var theCount_I = 0;
  var theCount_Y = 0;
  var theCount_W = 0;
  var wordsCount = words.length;
  for(var i=0;i<wordsCount;i++){
    var theWord = words.slice(i,i+1).toString().toLowerCase();
    if(theWord=="i"){
        theCount_I++;
//    }else if(theWord=="me"){
//        theCount_I++;
    }else if(theWord=="you"){
        theCount_Y++;
    }else if(theWord=="we"){
        theCount_W++;
    }else if(theWord=="us"){
        theCount_W++;
    }
  } 
  var message = "Here are the results : \n" 
  + "Number of words = "+ wordsCount + " \n"
  + "Number of 'I'= "+ theCount_I + " (" + (theCount_I/wordsCount*100) + ") \n"
  + "Number of 'You'= "+ theCount_Y+ " (" + (theCount_Y/wordsCount*100)  +") \n"
  + "Number of 'Us'= "+ theCount_W + " ("+ (theCount_W/wordsCount*100) + ")"; 
  Logger.log(message);
  //DocumentApp.getUi().alert(message);
  return message;
}
```

Here are the results :

Number of words = 283

Number of 'I'= 16 (5.6537102473498235)

Number of 'You'= 18 (6.36042402826855)

Number of 'Us'= 6 (2.1201413427561837)

Comment: Why are you are answering your own "question" (and there isn't one)? Are you trying to just show off your "code skills"?